LinkedIn unable to create app as logo upload fails
I opened a support ticket with LinkedIn who almost immediately closed said ticket and instead directed me to ask a question here.
Apologies for the question but it appears the form to create a new app requires an image upload for the app logo, but jpg, jpeg, png all fail with a message saying the image should be square at at least one dimension is 100px.

The image I resorted to testing with is a 100 x 100 black square, as everything else I tried also failed I suspect this is an issue with the validation of the image and not my form request.


Maybe check the reponse in the network tab, and also the logs. On my side I tried to upload a picture in order to test (square and above 100px) and it work so it should too for you.
